# WSO2 ESB: Address endpoint does not resume sending after backends recovery

Tags: wso2, rabbitmq, esb, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB with RabbitMQ, I have two proxy services:

- `AMQPProducerSample`, it receives messages via HTTP transport and send it to RabbitMQ queue
- `AMQPProxy` it works as consumer for RabbitMQ queue (via rabbitmq transport), consumed messages are send to HTTP endpoint `SampleEndPoint`

Everything works fine except one scenario:

1. My backend service set in `SampleEndPoint` goes down.
2. New messages arrives and are published via `AMQPProducerSample`, delivery fails (that is expected because my backend is down). In console I can see:

   ```
   WARN - ConnectCallback Connection refused or failed for : mfb.localhost/127.0.0.1:80
   WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_CODE : 101503
   WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_MESSAGE : Error connecting to the back end
   WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_DETAIL : Error connecting to the back end
   WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_EXCEPTION : null
   WARN - FaultHandler FaultHandler : Endpoint [SampleEndPoint]
   ```
3. My backend service recovers and is available
4. New messages arrives and are published via `AMQPProducerSample` but my endpoint **does not receive any message any more**. It works fine only if number of undelivered messages is below 5. In that case messages are successfully delivered to backend service. The delivery always stops working after 5 (five) undelivered messages.

How to solve this? Is there any option I need to set or change to make it work all the time?

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Below is my full config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.WSO2Registry">
        <parameter name="cachableDuration">15000</parameter>
    </registry>
    <proxy name="AMQPProxy"
           transports="rabbitmq"
           startOnLoad="true"
           trace="enable">
        <description/>
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <log level="full"/>
                <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
                <send>
                    <endpoint key="SampleEndPoint"/>
                </send>
            </inSequence>
        </target>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">exchange</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.routing.key">route</parameter>
    </proxy>
    <proxy name="AMQPProducerSample"
           transports="http"
           startOnLoad="true"
           trace="disable">
        <description/>
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
                <property name="NO_KEEPALIVE" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="rabbitmq:/AMQPProxy?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=queue&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=route&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=exchange"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
    <endpoint name="SampleEndPoint">
        <address uri="http://mfb.localhost/">
            <timeout>
                <duration>1000</duration>
                <responseAction>discard</responseAction>
            </timeout>
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
            </markForSuspension>
        </address>
    </endpoint>
    <sequence name="fault">
        <log level="full">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default 'fault' sequence"/>
            <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
            <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
        </log>
        <drop/>
    </sequence>
    <sequence name="main">
        <in>
            <log level="full"/>
            <filter source="get-property('To')" regex="http://localhost:9000.*">
                <send/>
            </filter>
        </in>
        <out>
            <send/>
        </out>
        <description>The main sequence for the message mediation</description>
    </sequence>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug which was there in ESB 4.8.1 fresh pack. Later on we have fixed it. So I recommend you to switch into ESB 4.9.0 release where this issue was fixed.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Downloading+the+Product

Comment: I am totally surprised that such serious bug was not fixed by patch in previous release (4.8.1). Anyway we upgraded our ESB to latest version (4.9.0) as you recommended.

Comment: This bug was fixed with a patch in ESB 4.8.1 version.

Comment: Can You tell me in which patch it was fixed? I just applied all patches I found here: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/wso2/carbon/WSO2-CARBON-PATCH-4.2.0/ but the problem still exits on 4.8.1

Comment: These patches are not available to the public. It is only available for those who get the production support.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the following parameter within transportReceiver for rabbitmq in axis2.xml

```
<parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.retry.count" locked="false">5</parameter>
```

"rabbitmq.connection.retry.count" is the number of times attempted to reconnect after each retry, I think you have set it to 5, that is why connection drop after five attempts. Increse the parameter value and try it.

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work. As far as I understand this option applies to connection between ESB and RabbitMQ server. In my case there is an issue between ESB (HTTP endpoint) and my backend server.

Comment: I did some debugging today (with ESB running in debug mode) and I found that connection thread is not removed from thread poll in case of failure. The thread poll size is hardcoded to 5 threads so after 5 failures delivery stops working.

Comment: Seems, ESB 4.8.1 fresh copy not supported for this, later with an official patch this has been fixed so without the patch we can't add the parameter " <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.retry.count" locked="false">5</parameter>". But with latest ESB release 4.9.0 this has been fixed.